# Updating an objectify entity without changing indexed properties

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

Say I have an objectify entity with 1 unindexed and 5 indexed fields. If I were to update the entity by modifying the unindexed property alone, would it cause to rewrite the indices for the five indexed fields as well? Essentially I am worried about the write cost here.

Answer (score 2):

Google charges per-entity write, irrespective of the number of indexes.

See https://cloud.google.com/appengine/pricing#costs-for-datastore-calls

Comment: My interpretation of this has been that the cost mentioned here is per write request, though I agree a more reasonable interpretation would be per entity write. My doubt arises because as explained in https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/datastore/entities#Python_Understanding_write_costs a single entity write can actually cause tens of write requests.

Comment: That documentation appears to be out of date; that's how it used to work. For better or worse, Google now charges per entity write.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, every update of an entity causes updates of all indexed properties. In other words, the write costs are the same whether only one property is updated or all of them.

This is not specific to Objectify - it's how the Datastore works.

Comment: This was not correct back before the pricing change and certainly isn't now. Current pricing is flat-rate per entity, irrespective of the number of indexes.

Comment: What is not correct ??? Your response is exactly the same as mine - the writing costs do not depend on the number of indexed properties, i.e. the writing costs are the same regardless of how many properties are updated.

Comment: I highly doubt it would be independent of number of indexed properties - why would Google go on to explain write costs as in here https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/datastore/entities#Python_Understanding_write_costs. What incentive does a developer have to leave a property unindexed?

Comment: 1. The pricing has recently changed. The documentation paged you linked to is now outdated. 2. The pricing is per data stored. The more indexed properties you have, the larger the total size of your data. You can look at the Dashboard under Datastore in your cloud console, and you will see that indexes often take several times more space than the data itself.

Comment: Sorry, the phrase "every update of an entity causes updates of all indexed properties" is confusing. In the old billing model GAE only counted write operations for indexed properties that changed; in the new billing model only whole entity writes are counted.

Comment: @stickfigure: The documentation states: `"The Cloud Datastore API does not distinguish between creating a new entity and updating an existing one."` It follows that whether one property has been changed or all of them, it makes no difference to the way it is processed. If you have a reference that only indexes with changed properties are  updated, I would love to see it. It makes no difference to the costs now, but it might have some implications for performance.

Comment: I don't have any reference to the old documentation, and no good way of finding it without hours in archive.org. Nevertheless, I'm 99% certain about this; the datastore tracked real index operations (deletes and creates) distinct from how many times you put() an entity (you still paid the 1 write for the entity, though). Remember there was no index "update", only delete and create; a genuine update was billed as 2 writes.